# Count days until sum of cases is minimum 5 - R dyplyr solution

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have a dataset with days and cases per day (eg. illness, produced srews, ...)

Now I want to calculate, how long it lasts until a predefined amount is reported/ produced.

Here a simple example:
I have ten days, per day in 'cases' is given how many cases were reported on this day.

Aim is to get a colum, how long it lasts for each day until (minimum) 5 cases are reported.

My data:

```
dates<-c("10.03.2020","11.03.2020","12.03.2020","13.03.2020","14.03.2020",
         "15.03.2020","16.03.2020","17.03.2020","18.03.2020","19.03.2020")
cases<-c(0,1,2,2,6,2,2,1,5,1)
dftest<-data.frame(dates,cases)

        dates cases
1  10.03.2020     0
2  11.03.2020     1
3  12.03.2020     2
4  13.03.2020     2
5  14.03.2020     6
6  15.03.2020     2
7  16.03.2020     2
8  17.03.2020     1
9  18.03.2020     5
10 19.03.2020     1
```

And my expected Result. (Column 'days5cases' can also be numeric only):

```
        dates cases days5cases
1  10.03.2020     0      4days
2  11.03.2020     1      3days
3  12.03.2020     2      3days
4  13.03.2020     2      2days
5  14.03.2020     6       1day
6  15.03.2020     2      3days
7  16.03.2020     2      3days
8  17.03.2020     1      2days
9  18.03.2020     5       1day
10 19.03.2020     1       <NA>
```

EDIT:

Some examples for calculating 'days5cases'

- 10.03.2020 4days because: 5 is reached at 13.03.2020 (0+1+2+2 = 5)
- 11.03.2020 3days because: 5 is reached at 13.03.2020 (1+2+2 = 5)
- 12.03.2020 3days because: 5 is reached at 14.03.2020 (2+2+6 = 10 > 5)
- 13.03.2020 2days because: 5 is reached at 14.03.2020 (2+6 = 8 > 5)
- 14.03.2020 1day because:  5 is reached at 14.03.2020 (6 > 5)
- and so on...

My Question:

How can I sum up column 'cases' until 5 cases are reached? Start for calculating is each day in dates.

Thank you for any idea to solve this problem ....

I tried from package `runner` `sum_run`, but here it is only possible to get the sum for the next 5 days.

Simmilary is `rollapply` from package `zoo`.

Stay healthy!

Comment: Why row 2 and 3 both have 3 days when they have different `dates`? Can you explain how you calculate `days5cases` ?

Comment: eg. 10.03.2020 4 days because: 5 is reached at 13.03.2020 (0+1+2+2 = 5)

Comment: I made an EDIT for some examples to calculate 'days5cases'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a row for each day using `sapply` we could iterate over each row, calculate the cumulative sum from that row till last row and return the index number where it first touches total cumulative sum to 5.

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(dftest)), function(i) 
       which(cumsum(dftest$cases[i:nrow(dftest)]) >= 5)[1])

#[1]  4  3  3  2  1  3  3  2  1 NA
```

---

To do this in `tidyverse` we can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dftest %>%
   mutate(days5cases = map_dbl(row_number(), 
                           ~which(cumsum(cases[.x:n()]) >= 5)[1]))


#        dates cases days5cases
#1  10.03.2020     0          4
#2  11.03.2020     1          3
#3  12.03.2020     2          3
#4  13.03.2020     2          2
#5  14.03.2020     6          1
#6  15.03.2020     2          3
#7  16.03.2020     2          3
#8  17.03.2020     1          2
#9  18.03.2020     5          1
#10 19.03.2020     1         NA
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm not familiar with (s)apply function - that's it.

Comment: I wonder, if there is a solution for counting backwards as well. Given the last day, how many days was it to full fill 5 cases.? I just arrange my dataset by date descending, take your code and arrange the dataset again ascending. But it seems to be not possible to do this within one pipe(line), because I have to store the sorted dataframes befor using your code. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `arrange`, run the code rearrange `dftest %>%
  arrange(n():1) %>%
  mutate(days5cases = map_dbl(row_number(), 
                              ~which(cumsum(cases[.x:n()]) >= 5)[1])) %>%
  arrange(1:n())`